# How to import url of the nodes via feeds

Tags: feeds

When I use url field in feeds import the url does not get imported for some reason

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIRC because the link field is multiple fields (title, link, description, etc.) you need to map it to the correct one, from quick google searching it seems the Link module dev version has a migrate file in it for this.